# How Can we implement search functionality in AxAcroPDFLib.AxAcroPDF( Pdf ) using C#

Tags: c#, pdf

I am using the AxAcroPDFLib.AxAcroPDF library to Display the  files in the winforms Control using the line,

```
AxAcroPDFLib.AxAcroPDF.src = path;
```

It's loaded the file well and when we click CTRL+F it showing
search box and searching the searched string well.

But we need to
implement the search functionality programatically using the Dotnet
Code to automatically search the  string in pdf file.

To do so I didn't
find any supported methods to  find the string programatically.

Please provide the solution to implement the search functionality in PDF files.

Answer (score 2):

As best I have been able to figure out, this ActiveX control does not implement a text search function. As a workaround, which is kind of a kludge but adequate for what I wanted: assuming you have declared the control as a AxAcroPDFLib.AxAcroPDF object, say pdfFoo, first select the control, then use SendKeys.Send to do the text search, something like (this is VB, but C# should work the same):

```
pdfFoo.Select()
SendKeys.Send("^f")  'send control-f to get search box
SendKeys.Flush()
SendKeys.Send("text to search for")
SendKeys.Flush()
```